# how to add new fields in form builder module though custom module

Tags: webforms

I am new to drupal, I want to add my own fileds into [Form Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder) module though my own custom module. Please help me whether is there any hook to add new fields in to [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)/[Form Builder](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fform_builder&ei=RtDqVIeMNcX9oQTxtoHQDw&usg=AFQjCNE-4ldTaWuyX4RT-1Qs0v8aTBthPQ&bvm=bv.86475890,d.cGU) module from custom module.

Comment: Reference link : http://devblog.more-onion.com/adding-your-own-fields-field-palette-formbuilder

Comment: hi, Thanks for this link.by following this tutorial i am able to add new fields but the the properties of that fields are not coming. i am getting the default form_builder properties only. and after save that form the my custome field is not able to edit formate.